# What is the difference between Nagle algorithm and 'stop and wait'?

Tags: sockets, ip, protocols, tcp

I saw the socket option `TCP_NODELAY`, which is used to turn on or off the Nagle alorithm.

I checked what the Nagle algorithm is, and it seems similar to 'stop and wait'.

Can someone give me a clear difference between these two concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a stop and wait protocol, one

- sends a message to the peer
- waits for an ack for that message
- sends the next message

(i.e. one cannot send a new message until the previous one has been acknowledged)

Nagle's algorithem as used in TCP is orthoginal to this concept. When the TCP application sends some data, the protocol buffers the data and waits a little while to see if there's more data to be sent instead of sending data to the peer immediately.

If the application has more data to send in this small timeframe, the protocol stack merges that data into the current buffer and can send it as one large message.

This concept could very well be applied to a stop and go protocol as well. (Note that TCP is not a stop and wait protocol)

Answer (score 1):

The [Nagle Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) is used to control whether the socket provider sends outgoing data immediately as-is at the cost of less efficient network transmissions (off), or if it buffers outgoing data so it can make more efficient network transmissions at the cost of speed (on).

[Stop and Wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop-and-wait_ARQ) is a mechanism used to ensure the integrity of transmitted data, by making the sender send a frame of data and then wait for an acknowledgement from the receiver before sending another frame, thus ensuring frames are received in the same order in which they are sent.

These two features operate independently of each other.